# ASP.NET Chart Line Chart Controls

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, graph, charts

I'm currently trying to generating a line chart just like in the online visual studios tool. Example: https://i.stack.imgur.com/H5RLk.png -- I would post this as an image but I don't have the reputation points yet :(

My platform is asp.net web forms in vb.net 2.0. My clients wants to be able to pull down the generated graph to a .png whenever they want.

I've looked around and have not been able to find any nifty tools/controls to assist me. In my other work, I've used Telerik charting, and it's been a breeze; even in winforms they have a charting graph control, however for asp.net I can't find anything. My current tactic is manually generating the bitmap images, however this is a lot more work than just using a prebuilt control.

This is my current demo, but it seems like a lot of heavy lifting for something so rudimentary.

I have an image with the source of this .ashx file, I can just send the params using a get and parse through that in the processrequest method, (or abstract that out using another method but you probably get the gist)

```
Public Sub ProcessRequest(ByVal context As HttpContext) Implements IHttpHandler.ProcessRequest

    context.Response.ContentType = "image/jpeg"
    createBitMapLineGraph().Save(context.Response.OutputStream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg)
End Sub


Private Function createBitMapLineGraph() As System.Drawing.Bitmap
    Dim bitmap As New System.Drawing.Bitmap(500, 500)
    Dim graphics As System.Drawing.Graphics = System.Drawing.Graphics.FromImage(bitmap)
    graphics.Clear(Drawing.Color.LightGray)

    ''draw axis
    graphics.FillRectangle(New System.Drawing.SolidBrush(Drawing.Color.Black), 0, 0, 5, 500)
    graphics.FillRectangle(New System.Drawing.SolidBrush(Drawing.Color.Black), 0, 495, 500, 5)

    Return bitmap
End Function
```

I guess ultimately, my question is, is there a better way? If you were tasked with this requirement, what would you do?

Sorry if this is the wrong venue for this sort of question. Thanks for your time.

edit:  <strike>I may have found what I'm looking for here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd489237.aspx</strike>

I guess I glossed over this when looking through the MSDN documentation. Still open to suggestions though!

It looked like that control was for .net 4.0 and up.